# Symfony 4 - Doctrine DQL select collection object doesn't work

Tags: arrays, symfony, collections, doctrine, dql

I have a problem with a DQL query on Symfony. In fact I have an entity Absence, and in the repository I want to return all absences, grouped by type of absence.

For example we would have:

```
0 => array:2
    "absences" => Collection(or array, with all Absences objects)
    "type" => "Heures supp"
1 => array:2
    "absences" => Collection(or array, with all Absences objects)
    "type" => "RTT"
...
```

So I did my function:

```
public function getAbsencesValidees($user)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("a")
            ->select("a as absences, t.nom as type")
            ->join("a.typeConge", "t")
            ->where("a.user = :user")
            ->andWhere("a.etat = 'Validée'")
            ->groupBy("t.nom")
            ->setParameter("user", $user)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

But suddenly in the attribute "absences", he puts me only the first object. He does not put me all the absences related to the guy.
However, if I withdraw the reference

```
->groupBy("t.nom")
```

well I have all the absences, but suddenly it's not grouped
So in the current state of things, I get this. So in the attribute "absences", he puts me only the first one that he finds and that corresponds, but he does not mention all the others who are part of it as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the use of `groupBy()`.
For what you want to do, you do not need `groupBy()`.

First, your query :

```
public function getUserAbsences(User $user) {
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder("absence");

    $qb->addSelect("partial typeConge.{id, nom}")
       ->join("absence.typeConge", "typeConge")
       ->andWhere("absence.user = :user")
       ->andWhere("absence.etat = 'Validée'")
       ->setParameter("user", $user);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Now, SQL result is not a multi-dimensional array, so in your controller, you have to filter this result.

```
public function userAbsences(AbsenceRepository $absenceRepository) {
    $absencesByType=array();
    $absences=$absenceRepository->getUserAbsences($this->getUser());

    foreach($absences as $absence) {
        $absencesByType[$absence->getTypeConge->getNom][]=$absence;
    }
}
```